# How to maintain order of insertion to Shared Preferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
editor.commit();
```

is it above code enough to preserve the order of insertion ???

Comment: what do you mean by order of insertion??

Comment: You mean you write the same key twice?

Comment: I don't see multiple insertions  in your code. Therre is no order if there is only one insertion.

Comment: @sumit (order of insertion) I mean first input data in shared preference should be at last position of listview

Comment: No @Henry I have unique key for all values

Comment: @VladMatvienko I have insertion data like                      01/Feb/17 13:07:3414
 02/Feb/17 13:07:3415
 03/Feb/17 13:07:3416
 04/Feb/17 13:07:3417
 28/Mar/17 13:07:3455
 29/Mar/17 13:07:3456
 30/Mar/17 13:07:3457
 31/Mar/17 13:07:3458
these are keys for shared preference

Comment: you didn't show how you make multiple insertions. That's why there is nothing to be said about the order. We don't know how you do that - we can'tsay anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't completely understand how SharedPreferences work. There is no order. Similar to a map, each entry has a key and a value. If you write a value to the SharedPreferences with a key that already exists, the new value will overwrite the old one. If you read the data from SharedPreferences, order doesn't matter, because you read the data using the keys. You can't iterate over data in SharedPreferences.

So when your intention is to save only the latest/highest highscore, the answer is: Yes, that code will work. But if you want to save something like a highscore list, your solution won't work. Then you would need unique keys for all values you want to save.